# Table overlapping div

Tags: html, css-tables, overlapping

I want to place a table at the bottom of the page but as soon as you resize the window/browser it overlaps the content above it.
When I put a table on the top of the page it does not overlap.

Any suggestions?

```
<div id="box">minimize/resize the window and the table will overlap my div...</div>
<table id="tables" border="0" bgcolor="silver">
  <tr>
   <td>My table</td>
  </tr>


#box {
    position: absolute;
    top:20px;
    width:200px;
    height:200px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}

#tables {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    bottom: 0%;
    height: 30%;
}
```

[Here is my Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bhLq4hgu/11/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Natural Z position in HTML (Document order of apperance for `position`ed elements):

```
<div>     >>> lower Z index 
<table>   >>> higher Z Index therefore overlaps DIV
```

logically:

```
<table>
</div>    >>> DIV will now overlap Table
```

Manually control the `z-index` property: *[demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bhLq4hgu/12/)*

```
<div>     >>> z-index:1; >>> DIV will now overlap Table
<table>   >>> Lower Z index
```

Comment: Thank you Roko, it kind of solved it, the main goal i want to achieve is to make all the elements stay where they are no matter what screen size etc. This solved the overlaping problem but i really would like to have it at the bottom at all times. I will keep trying! thanks.

Comment: @Gustaf Google than for `sticky footer`. I think that's what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Please, Update the Following Code in the CSS;

```
#box {
position: ;
top:20px;
width: 100%;
height:200px;
border: 1px solid black;
max-width:250px; /* or whatever width you want. */
display: inline-block;
}
```

Here,Give **width** property to 100% and  **max-width** property controls your text not to overlap the content as soon as resizing the window/browser.

Comment: Thanks, but that does not seem to solve it. The table at the bottom still overlaps the div box.